# The result always is 1, when inserting data in the same table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run the following query, and it does not show me run-time error, but it always gives 1 ...
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

```
UPDATE   scraper_data_twitter AS T1,
(
SELECT   Ntweets AS Ntweets_var,
         (SELECT COUNT(Ntweets) + 1
          FROM   scraper_data_twitter 
          WHERE  (NTweets > Ntweets_var) 
          AND    fecha = '2017-02-19'
         ) AS rank
FROM     scraper_data_twitter 
WHERE    fecha = '2017-02-19'
GROUP BY SITE, fecha
ORDER BY NTweets_var DESC
 ) AS A
SET T1.rnk_Ntweets =  A.rank
```

Image, Query Result without UPDATE
[image]

Image, Query Result WITH    UPDATE
[image]

Comment: I cannot make head nor tail of this query. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This can be written probably much better, but for now add this after the "AS A".

WHERE T1.ntweets = A.Ntweets_var

and see the result.

This is an implicit join (the comma after T1) so you need to put the condition for that join.

Comment: Hi Valentin, unfortunately that shows me a syntax error ..... I will greatly appreciate your suggestion about how you would improve this query ...  !!!

Comment: I am sorry, add that at the very end, and not where I said previously.

Comment: it already works, but it always leaves me 1 in the result, I was consulting to do it another way but MYSQL does not allow windows functions and with OVER () it could be ... so I have to look for another way, what do you suggest?

Comment: have you tried what I've suggested putting that WHERE at the end - it should give you the correct numbers.

Comment: Sure, that was the way the syntax error was avoided, but the result of the query is not as expected...

Comment: can you please post the query you are trying?

Comment: UPDATE   scraper_data_twitter AS T1,
(
SELECT   Ntweets AS Ntweets_var,
         (SELECT COUNT(Ntweets) + 1
          FROM   scraper_data_twitter 
          WHERE  (NTweets > Ntweets_var) 
          AND    fecha = '2017-02-19'
         ) AS rank
FROM     scraper_data_twitter 
WHERE    fecha = '2017-02-19'
GROUP BY SITE, fecha
ORDER BY NTweets_var DESC
 ) AS A
SET T1.rnk_Ntweets =  A.rank

Comment: and where have you added the part that I wrote: `WHERE T1.ntweets = A.Ntweets_var`

Comment: So Sorry for the delay in answering, I put it at the end of everything, and it's definite, it does not work, what I need is to fill that information by date, would you have a different option? Thank you